# my JSON is not practical and I want to change it, how can I do so?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Problem: my JSON isn't practical and I want to change it. As you can see my JSON looks strange, but somehow it's valid JSON (checked with JSONLint). I have input fields which are in containers with their own unique id (they increment). I was wondering if it's possible to send the data inserted into the input fields together so when I fetch it, it will stay together.

how my JSON looks like right now:

```
{
"main_object": {
    "id": "new",
    "formData": {
        "language": "nl_NL",
        "getExerciseTitle": "ExampleForStackOverflow",
        "question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[0": "ExampleForStackOverflow",
        "Syllablescounter[0": "Example",
        "Syllablescounter[1": "Example1",
        "question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[1": "SecondExampleForStackOverflow",
        "Syllablescounter[2": "Second",
        "Syllablescounter[3": "Example"
    }
  }
}
```

what I am looking and hoping to achieve:

```
{ "main_object": 
  {
  "id": "new",
  "formData": [
    {
        "language": "nl_NL", 
        "getExerciseTitle": "ExampleForStackOverflow",
        "Word": "ExampleForStackOverflow", 
        "Syllables":["Example", "Example1"]
    },
    {
        "Word": "SecondExampleForStackOverflow",
        "Syllables": ["Second", "Example"]
    }
]
   }
 };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/StackOverflowAccount/sa2eowhh/ I have a fiddle so you can see what I mean. When you click on the green + button it adds a whole field. This is a container that has an ID, I am trying to keep everything with the same ID with each other in the JSON file, so when I fetch it to my front-end it "knows" which syllables are part of the exercise word.

I have an ajax call which I think causes my JSON file to look like what I have right now.

my ajax call:

```
 function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
$("#my_form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveJson.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: getUrlParameter('id'),
            formData: JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI($('#my_form').serialize()).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}')
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response) {

    });
});
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where ever you get the JSON, it's best to fix it at the source.

Comment: Where ever I "get" the JSON? But I can't get the JSON for some odd reason, and if it were to be possible to fetch it, I would still encounter problems later on, because all the syllables and exercise words will be seperated, so when I want to make a check it will cause much more difficult time doing so.

Comment: On what basis you want to distribute **Syllablescounter** into multiple objects like you shown in your question ?

Comment: could you elaborate your question? If I understood you correctly your asking me: How do you want to distribute Syllablescounter into multiple objects? Well, (in my post there is a fiddle u can play with) I have containers I create with a green + button, and it adds containers with their own unique ID. I want to create distribute every syllablescounter and exercise word etc. based on the ID they had. So if I have 2 containers (id 1 and id 2) it keeps all the inserted data of id 1 together and it keeps all the inserted data of id 2 together